# Mandarin Chinese Most Frequent 1000 First Names (中国最常用的1000个名字)

Tags: names

Is there a list of common Chinese first names? There are some lists containing top 100 names but it is quite insufficient as it covers only 15% of total population. I need a comprehensive list.

(哪里可以找到中国最常用的1000个名字？有一些排名列出了最常用的100个，但是它不够充分，因为它仅覆盖15％的总人口。我需要一个完整列表。)

Comment: name or first name?

Comment: @Albert, first name sir, i have found 100 common surnames and it is sufficient statistically

Comment: 我的意思是，你说的是姓氏还是姓名？(Ahh, I mean family name or full name?)

Comment: I'm sorry, my English is not very good……

Comment: @Albert, i mean first name like 伟, 伟, 芳, it is okay to have full name list

Comment: Ahh, given name, got it!

Comment: 如果是given name的话，可能要让题主失望了……因为中国人起名字有很多讲究的，自己的生辰八字配合，还要趋吉避凶，还要做到“六忌一便于”。（六忌：一忌太易重名，二忌不辨性别，三忌谐音不雅，四忌充满稚气，五忌花枝招展，六忌一字多音；一便于：便于书写和认读，避免太生僻的字。）最好要有比较积极的寓意，有的在自己家族中有严格的字辈。所以想统计比较完整的会比较困难……

Comment: You might already be aware of this, but I should point out that Chinese naming conventions are not like those of, say, Anglophones. There isn't some big "list" of names from which parents pick and choose. Moreover, parents do not name children after other people, which would limit the ways in which names might converge.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's an official account for the top 1000 most used first names. But here is an interesting statistic I've found.

**In this image, it says the top 10 most used first names are:**

英(ying)，华(hua)，玉(yu)，秀(xiu)，文(wen)，明(ming)，兰(lan)，金(jin)，国(guo)，春(chun).

I think its pretty accurate tbh.

[image]

Comment: I take it that this data is only for mainland China?

Comment: @Maroon I guess so.